# drag a div and drop in a container is not happening in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

in drop function data value is getting empty ,so how to fix that if I want to drag and drop a div to a particular container. instead of getting the id its not fetching any value so its throws an error "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'"

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [isDown, setIsDown] = useState(false);

  const drag = document.querySelector(".drag");
  const Onmousedown = () => {
    setIsDown(true);
  };
  const Onmouseup = () => {
    setIsDown(true);
  };
  const Onmousemove = (e) => {
    console.log(e.clientX);
    if (isDown) {
      drag.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
      drag.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    }
  };
  function dragi(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }
  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
  function onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "350px",
          height: "70px",
          padding: "10px",
          border: "1px solid #aaaaaa"
        }}
        id="div1"
        onDrop={(event) => drop(event)}
        onDragOver={onDragOver}
      ></div>
      <div
        className="drag"
        onMouseDown={(e) => Onmousedown(e)}
        onMouseUp={(e) => Onmouseup(e)}
        onMouseMove={(e) => Onmousemove(e)}
        style={{
          width: "50px",
          height: "50px",
          background: "yellow"
        }}
        draggable="true"
        onDragStart={(event) => dragi(event)}
      >
        Drag
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was because you didn't specify `id` for the draggable element:

```
 <div
        className="drag"
        onMouseDown={(e) => Onmousedown(e)}
        onMouseUp={(e) => Onmouseup(e)}
        onMouseMove={(e) => Onmousemove(e)}
        style={{
          width: "50px",
          height: "50px",
          background: "yellow"
        }}
        draggable="true"
        onDragStart={(event) => dragi(event)}
      >
```

once you add a `id` to this element it will work.

[image: Edit nifty-sara-70umos]